# composer global require laravel/installer not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed composer successfully.

But when I run `composer global require laravel/installer`  command I am getting the following errors below.

Even, I am getting the same error when I run `composer create-project/install/update`.

I am using `php version 7.3.10` , `composer 1.9.0` `Ubuntu 18.04`

[image: screenshot composer error message]

Comment: probably check your network
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4142#issuecomment-117648869

Comment: It was IPv6 issue, I have fixed my IPv6 setup now everything is alright.

The solution link:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-